# Remove HEAD from HTML from AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I'm replacing the body html with ajax received html.
the problem is that I have duplicated HEAD section.

I first need to remove the whole lines till  from the received html and then use:

```
$('body').html(data);
```

I'm getting the html as result from POST.
This is a well formatted html.

I'm using Django's render_to_response to send the response back.

How can I achieve such thing?

Comment: use jQuery load with a page fragment. Read the docs.

Comment: Please post more of your code. Like your ajax request. Check jQuery `.load()` method.

Comment: Expanding on epascarello's comment, wouldn't you be able to exclude the `head` server-side? That's the best way to handle that.

Comment: I'm using Django's render_to_response.
I have no control on the server-side.

Comment: You should probably tag the question with django btw. You're more likely to get a better answer than mine then.

Comment: Paste your `render_to_response` code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try `$('body').html($(data).find('body'));`. This will work if you have well-formed HTML.

Edit: this won't work; see Fabricio's comment below and my reply for why. One workaround is to wrap everything inside your `body` in a div with a given ID, then select for this ID like so: `$('body').html($(data).filter('#chosenid'));` Of course, this is really no different from saying `$('body').load('remote_page.html #chosenid');` which combines the AJAX call into the same request.

Comment: I guess not. `html`/`body`/`head` tags are automatically excluded when parsing an HTML string. http://jsfiddle.net/hqJjM/1/

Comment: won't `$(data).find('body')` be an object?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté You're right; found this on the JQuery API page for $(): When passing in complex HTML, some browsers may not generate a DOM that exactly replicates the HTML source provided. As mentioned, jQuery uses the browser"s .innerHTML property to parse the passed HTML and insert it into the current document. During this process, some browsers filter out certain elements such as <html>, <title>, or <head> elements. As a result, the elements inserted may not be representative of the original string passed.

Comment: Yes. My studies on jQuery's parsing show that it utilizes a separate documentFragment to insert the data, then extracts the parsed elements and appends to the target. AFAIK documentFragments are not allowed to contain `html`/`body`/`head` elements.

Comment: Yes, your edit now *would* work. Just one thing though. `#chosenid` would be in the top level, meaning you should use `.filter()` instead of `.find()` I think. Needs testing on the fiddle.

Comment: +1 as this should be theoretically faster than regex'ing the data. `:P`

Comment: perfect solution guys!
I already have a div right after main.

mind explaining why using filter is better than find?

Comment: Got the answer why using filter is better.
10x again!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend excluding the `head` server-side, but as I have no idea how you'd do that in django, here's a hackish  and extremely ugly solution that at least works, unlike other solutions with `$(data).find('body')` which will never match any element due to jQuery parsing automatically excluding `body` tags alongside `html` and `head` ones.

Behold, the power of Regex!

```
$('body').html(/<body[\s\S]*?>([\s\S]*?)<\/body>/.exec(data)[1]);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hqJjM/2/)

I do not recommend using this for production environment as sending over the `head` is just wasted bandwidth on both ends and the regex isn't the most suitable solution. It should at least work for development until you make the switch to server partial pages to your ajax requests.

Answer (score 0):

These solutions all seem very hacky... Seriously, just remove the head on the server side!!

If you're using render_to_ response, you must be passing it a template name to render. In that template, just don't write any head code! Simply put the code that will go between the body tags, and you're good to go.

Comment: FYI I did recommend removing the `head` server-side in my answer instead of using the temporary work-around which I posted before you called it very hackish and down voted it.

Comment: I down-voted it because it was a very hacky response, which really shouldn't be used. It is *easy* to remove the head of a page from django - as you're writing all the HTML yourself! A hacky answer shouldn't be considered the 'best' answer, when there are easy and recommended ways of doing this.

Comment: Fine then. If you can't bother to read the last paragraph on my answer I won't bother arguing.

Answer (score -1):

Are you inserting text into you body?
You should use the [load-method](http://api.jquery.com/load/), but beware of scripts :)

```
$("body").load("yourNextPage.html");
```

Comment: Yes, html text received from server response